# MapFragment : Set Minimum zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, mapfragment

I'm currently developing an android application which uses the Google Maps API V2. As you can see in the topic title, the Map class extends MapFragment. What I want to do is set a minimum zoom so that, we could see all the continents on the screen when we zoom out. Currently, we can't see all the continents with the default map settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible to show entire world, but it has already been requested on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5724). Star that issue to give it a higher priority.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope Google will "fix" it some day.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the position of the camere + zoom level in this way:

```
mCameraZoom = 15.00f;
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(l, mCameraZoom)));
```